# Nginx is not proxying to the node backend

Tags: express, nginx, proxy, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have react application running on Nginx and backend application on Nodejs(running on another port 8080) with routes of patterns "`/org-metadata/**, /proxy-api/**, /node-api/**`".

I am trying to proxy the nginx to nodejs running on 8080, but it does not reach the backend. and the nginx gives the `503 Service Unavailable` response and some times response 200 with You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

Can some one pls point where am I missing anything?

Below is my nginx.conf file :

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 8000;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server {
        # listen on port 80
        listen 80;

        # where the root here
        root /var/www;
        # what file to server as index
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to redirecting to index.html
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        # Javascript and CSS files
        location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            expires 1y;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        location ~ (proxy-api|org-metadata|node-api) {
            try_files $uri @nodejs;
        }

        location @nodejs {
            proxy_pass http://nodejs:8080;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
            add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
            add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the regex operator. Try: `location ~ (proxy-api|org-metadata|node-api) { ... }`

Comment: Have added `~` but still dint work

Comment: @RichardSmith Just missed to add earlier the request gives me 503

Comment: Is the service running on port 8080 providing an http or https connection?

Comment: its http connection